How to subscribe on signal change event in Spark AR?
I have a simple TargetTracker in a scene
(async function() {
    const [
        tracker
    ] = await Promise.all([
        Scene.root.findFirst('targetTracker0')
    ]);

    ...

and i am trying to perform an action when target trcker detects its object. Now, i have read in the community gitbook that it has a property called isTracking, which outputs a BoolSignal.
Now, i'm trying to subscribe to an event of this signal changing and i don't seem to be able to work. So far from googling around i have this
    tracker.isTracking.monitor().subscribe(function (val) {
        if(val){
            fireAnimations();
        }else{
            haltAnimations();
        }
    });

However, this doesn't seem to work, and i cannot really debug it, as i don't know how to Diagnostics.log event from a real camera (or how to simulate TargetTracker detection change in the studio)
